# How to put the first different header in DomPDF

Tags: php, css, dompdf

I'm using the following html ([Print Header Footer Example](https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/core_tests/print_header_footer.html)) as a template, but I'd like to put the first different header.

My CSS doesn't work

I create a a inside

I added the CSS below:

```
.headerc {
  background-color: rgb(4, 255, 0);
}

.headerc:first {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

But all a gets .headerc, I'd like the first of a to receive the stylization of the .headerc:first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `:first` is not a valid pseudo class selector as used in your code

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

And to show or hide elements of a printed page, you can use `@media print`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#media_types

See css `@media print` -> https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/